# SecureString as a dependency property, is it safe to bind a Password?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Im working on a WPF behaviour for the `PasswordBox` component,and i created a dependency property of type `SecureString` to bind to the viewmodels that are using that behaviour.

im never binding the plain text string,and im only accessing the string via conversions, im never saving it at any point on a variable.

the question is : is it really safe to do so? since im using a dp it is kept in memory (but should be crypted since it is a `SecureString` and not a plain text string)

Comment: [Are you sure you want to be using `SecureString`?](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)

Comment: Did you read the remarks in the help for Secure string https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0#remarks (hint, it points to @MatthewWatson's GitHub link)

Comment: in that situation i can't use certificates, i need to use a pwd

Comment: In general, if you are working on a desktop app (like WPF), it is nearly impossible to prevent leaking secrets.  If it's in an enterprise environment, you have some chance of getting it right.  In particular, you can look at encrypted sections of a `.config` file

Answer (score 1):

It is safe enough. It provides more protection than `string` does and allows you to process the entered password.

The concerns surrounding `SecureString` are related to the fact that it does not completely hide it's value but just shortens the time interval where it is exposed. However, in order to exploit this, an attacker would need to be able to read the data from processes running on the host machine. As long as the host machine is secure, you do not have to worry.

The recommendations in the GitHub documentation for `SecureString` (https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md) of using certificates or windows authentication is not appropriate if password based authentication is a requirement so using `SecureString` when you need to process a password is acceptable.

Comment: my doubt is if it is not safe since SecureString is saved as dependency properties and dependency properties keep their values unencrypted in memory

Comment: @Light1203 Have you read [How secure is SecureString?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0#HowSecure) It should make no difference whether you store it as a dependency property or a regular property, like PasswordBox does.

Comment: @Light1203 it doesn't really matter what kind of property you use. As mentioned in my answer, in order to exploit ```SecureString``` an attacker would need to have a malicious process/application running on the host machine, which is a scenario in which you are completely compromised in so many ways anyway.